# Dudas con Timer android studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

Tengo el siguiente código de un Timer que hace una cuenta atrás de 3 segundos

El problema es que se retroalimenta una y otra vez y no veo la forma de detenerlo

Alguien me puede explicar como funciona y porque la sentencia "timer3.cancel()" no funciona ?

```
//método de cuenta atrás
private void time3() {
    //instancio el Timer
    timer3 = new Timer();
    
    timer3.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        //inicia el timer
        public void run() {

            //al valor inicial de la variable, que he puesto en 4, le descuento 1
            midTime3--;
            //calculo la operación para trabajar en segundos
            long ss3 = midTime3 % 60;

            //si el segundo es cero
            if (ss3 == 0) {
                //borro el texto del textView
                txtRelojEjercicio2.setText("");
                //Vuelvo a darle el valor de 4 a la variable, pues se volverá a llamar al método en breve
                midTime3 = 4;
                //cancelo en Timer3 en marcha
                //lo que deseo es detener el Timer hasta que que vuelva a ser llamado el método
                timer3.cancel();
            }
            //si el segundo está entre 4 y 1
            else if ((ss3 < 5) && (ss3 > 0)) {
                //escribo la cuenta atrás en el TextView
                txtRelojEjercicio2.setText("00:0" + ss3 + "");
            }
        }
    //argumentos del timer para que se ejecute cada segundo
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

Deseo detener el timer, pero éste se reinicia una y otra vez

Alguien me puede poner alguna luz al respecto ?

Graciassss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para crear un Timer que se ejecute solo una vez se realiza de esta forma, si notas, solo se tiene un parámetro que indica el tiempo que transcurrira para que se ejecute la tarea:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Realiza proceso.
    }
}, 1000); // 1 segundo
```

Para que tu timer se ejecute solo una ocasión debes usar este constructor:

> [schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)) Programa la tarea
> especificada para que se ejecute después del retraso especificado.

En tu caso estas usando un constuctor diferente el cual se ejecutaría repetidamente cada segundo.

> [schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) Programa la
> tarea especificada para una ejecución repetida con demora fija,
> comenzando después de la demora especificada.

Por lo tanto, para que se ejecute solo una vez después de 1 segundo, se debe definir de esta forma:

```
timer3.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    //inicia el timer
    public void run() {
      ...
       //Realiza proceso.
      ...    
    }
//Se ejecuta solo una vez después de cada segundo.
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hostia @Jorgesys, gracias por tu respuesta. intentaré adaptar mi código en base a tus explicaciones. Me has quitado varios quebraderos de cabeza.

Comment: Excelente @el.trasgu! , saludos.